# Finding rows that map to the same value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with mappings:

```
|id|from|to|
|1 | 12 |AB|
|2 | 34 |CD|
|3 | 56 |AB|
|4 | 67 |EF|
|5 | 89 |CD|
|6 | 01 |GH|
|7 | 23 |CD|
```

How do I find rows that map to the same `to` value?

So the query would ideally result in something like:

```
|id|from|to|
|1 | 12 |AB|
|3 | 56 |AB|
|2 | 34 |CD|
|5 | 89 |CD|
|7 | 23 |CD|
```

Is there an efficient way to do this in SQL?

Comment: What is your Oracle version? (Don't guess - run `SELECT * FROM V$VERSION` and report the full version number. Mine, for example, is 12.1.0.2.0.)

Comment: @mathguy Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
"CORE 12.1.0.2.0 Production"
TNS for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the *analytic* `count()` function to show how many rows have the same `to` value **on each row**. Then you can use that in an outer query to filter out the rows with a count of 1.

This approach has the advantage that the base data is read only once (as opposed to twice in many other approaches). Of course, this is only important if execution time matters - if you have a lot of data, and/or if you must run this query frequently.

```
select id, from, to
from   (
         select id, from, to, count(*) over (partition by to) as cnt
         from   my_table
       )
where  cnt > 1
;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from your_table
where "to" in (select "to" from your_table group by "to" having count(*) > 1)
order by "to"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this with `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.to = t.to and t2.id <> t.id);
```

I offer this because under some circumstances (particularly with an index on `(to, id)`, this may be the fastest approach.

Answer (score -3):

`select * from table_name order by to,from`

Comment: As you can see when looking at the other answers, the issue is slightly more complex than juist ordering by to, from.